# iOS What Provisioning Profile used for when build configuration is RELEASE mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, signing

I'm signing app using "Automatically manage signing".

If I change "Build Configuration" to "Release" mode,
What provisioning profile used for build an app?
Release(Production) or Development?

Is there anyway to check what provisioning profile (Development or Production) used for building app after app running?

[image]

---

[image]

When I testing remote push notification, I set build configuration to "Release", could not receive any notification from server using production .p12 file.
But when I downloaded app from TestFlight-this must be using production provisioning profile, I can receive notification.
I don't know why this was happen.
I think I also set entitlement files properly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Debug -> Development. Release -> Production.

Comment: @rmaddy I though too. But when I testing remote push notification, I set build configuration to "Release", could not receive any notification from server using production .p12 file. But when I downloaded app from TestFlight, I can receive notification. Why this happend?